# plotting real time graphs in android studio - raspberry pi

Tags: android, raspberry-pi

I'm new with Android Studio and Raspberry pi and i need help.

I want to develop a mobile app for a smart irrigation system using raspberry pi.I connected all the sensors to raspberry and they are working: temperature, soil moisture,light intensity and rain sensor.
I made the login page in android studio using firebase and i also made the dashboard.I made a python program to start the pump  based on some operating requirements.
So now i want to plot the real-time graphs for all the sensors.

How can I plot the real-time graphs?
How can I make the python program to run in real-time so the pump can start automatically?

I want a brief description of what I need to do next and what technologies I need to use.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Project Architect should have to think though this long before you started implementation. I would suggest you to talk to him/her about this :-) But if this is the hobby project then you need to use some external server like [Adafruit IO](https://io.adafruit.com/) or any other IoT service which is free for small number of IoT devices. Your daemon then would both control pump and send data to the external server and your app would pick that data from server.

Comment: It's a hobby project.Thanks for your help , I think I'm going to use the real-time database from firebase to store the data from raspberry pi and then plot the data in android studio.